# left join if condition met , set to null

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to write a sql join query for below tables.

I am trying get as in expected table.

The only join condition is that , if In table 1, the value of operation is 'D' i.e deleted, then the corresponding value of rows from table 2 should be null.

The table joined based on the key.

DB: POSTGRES

**Table 1**

```
id | operation| keys|
-----------------------
1  | I        | 1   |
2  | U        | 2   |
3  | D        | 3   |
```

**Table 2**

```
id |keys| col1| col2
-----------------------
1  | 1  | xyz | abc
2  | 2  | yxz | cba
3  | 3  | zxy | bac
```

**Expected Output**

```
id | operation| keys| col1| col2
---------------------------------
1  | I        | 1   | xyz |abc
2  | U        | 2   | yxz |cba
3  | D        | 3   | NULL|NULL
```

Comment: How are the tables related? By ID? By key? By ID + key? Or is one key the other table's ID? You should at least have posted the query where you join the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired result using `CASE WHEN`.
Basically, the query will look like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.operation, t1.keys,
CASE WHEN t1.operation = 'D' THEN NULL ELSE t2.col1 END col1,
CASE WHEN t1.operation = 'D' THEN NULL ELSE t2.col2 END col2
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.keys = t2.keys;
```

I don't know if you really want to do a left join or if you need an inner join instead. And I don't know if you will join on both id and keys columns or on one of them only. So the query will produce the expected result for your example, but you have to check these things, please.
A last note: You could of course even just remove the "CASE WHEN" construct and put the != 'D' condition in the left join. I did not propose this since the "CASE WHEN" construct easy allows you to select different values for col1 and col2 if necessary, so it's more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just write a `left join` statement with the right conditions, in this case `table_1.keys = table_2.keys and table_1.operation != 'D'`. This will join the second table and you will get `null` in the columns where the condition was `false`.

```
select t1.*, t2.col1, t2.col2  from table_1 as t1 left join table_2 as t2 on (t1.keys = t2.keys and t1.operation != 'D')
```

See demo at [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/b79f09c6)

Comment: The join is ok, but the result differs from the output the OP wanted since you use the * operator. This is a very bad idea, you need to write a proper column selection.